# Json is not declared error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have the following view Model in my mvc app.

```
Public Class SiteCatModel

Public Property SiteCatValue As String
Public Property SiteCatDescription As String


Private Function GetSiteCategories() As List(Of SiteCatModel)

    Dim sitCategoryList = New List(Of SiteCatModel)() From {
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "A",
    .SiteCatDescription = "A - 24 x 7"},
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "B",
    .SiteCatDescription = "B - xxxxxx"
        },
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "C",
        .SiteCatDescription = "C - xxxxx"
        },
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "D",
        .SiteCatDescription = "D - xxxxx"
        },
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "E",
        .SiteCatDescription = "E - xxxxx"
        },
        New SiteCatModel() With {.SiteCatValue = "Z",
        .SiteCatDescription = "Z - ?????"
        }
    }

    Return sitCategoryList

End Function

    Public Function GetSiteCategoryData() As JsonResult
        Dim siteCategories = GetSiteCategories()
        Return JSon(siteCategories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    End Function

End Class
```

In the final function the Return **Json** has an error highlighted in Visual Studio 2015 which says **JSon is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level**.

I have tried searching for possible fixes but all my results are about errors in IE... this error is in VS and I can't build the app so I'm not even getting to errors from a browser yet.

Comment: Do you need [Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method? Your class does not inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` for it to be accessible...

Comment: @EekTheCat Dohhhhh... Inherited System.Web.Mvc Controller and job done... Thanks.... make it an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need [Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json) method? Your class does not inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` for it to be accessible.